# how to use a generic way to pass callback data

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, serialization, datacontractserializer

Is it possible to pass generic objects to client, by generic I mean any with DataContract.Using a generic way to send or rceive different types of object.At the moment I have something like this:
`enter code here`

```
 [DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(Type1))]
[KnownType(typeof(Type2))]
[KnownType(typeof(Type3))]
public class Type
{
    [DataMember]
    private string id;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id= value; }
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Type1: Type
{
    private SchoolData school;
    [DataMember]
    public SchoolData School
    {
        get { return school; }
        set { school= value; }
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Type2: Type
{
    private TecherData techer;
    [DataMember]
    public TecherData Techer
    {
        get { return techer; }
        set { techer= value; }
    }
}
[DataContract]
public class Type3 : Type
{
    private StudentData student;
    [DataMember]
    public StudentData Student
    {
        get { return student; }
        set { student= value; }
    }
}
public interface ICallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void CallbackData(Type object)
}
```

So ,I want send type1 type2,type3 by a generic way to the clent side,I want to pass a generic objects as I have vast collection of objects (Class Type1/Type2/Type) .
Thank you~

Answer (score 0):

Its not really a "Data Contract" if I can send any type through :-) To be honest you are really trying to reproduce Json here - sending of dynamically constructed types is what its designed for. Data Contracts are for statically defined types which you can validate and attach business rules to.

Comment: Thank you very much ,it helpful for me.